# How to plot a cube with regular step points with Matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I would like to plot a cube with regular step points.

I wrote a function to do it:

```
    def buildCube(self, x_center, y_center, z_center, step, cote):
    x = []
    y = []
    z = []
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    for i in range(-cote/2, cote/2, step):
        for j in range(-cote/2, cote/2, step):
            for k in range(-cote / 2, cote / 2, step):
                z.append(k + z_center)
                y.append(j + y_center)
                x.append(i + x_center)

    ax.scatter(x, x, z, s=8, c="g", depthshade=True)
    ax.set_xlabel("X")
    ax.set_ylabel("Y")
    ax.set_zlabel("Z")
    ax.set_title("Le cube")
    plt.show()
```

But it does not work as expected. I get the result bellow (I got a square not a cube).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ax.scatter(x, x, z, s=8, c="g", depthshade=True)
```

Should probably be

```
ax.scatter(x, y, z, s=8, c="g", depthshade=True)
```